# How a program is executed on a CPU with 3 level of caches?

Tags: memory, cpu, cache, cpu-cache

We have a system optimization problem that requires a clear workflow of the execution of a CPU.  How does a modern CPU (e.g. Intel Xeon) with multiple levels of caches execute a program originally stored on a hard drive of a computer?

I know roughly the program is first loaded to memory, and then, the CPU decodes the instructions and get the data needed from the memory. But, What is the detailed workflow of a CPU loading instructions from DRAM with all possible level of caches involved (maybe from DRAM to the L3 cache, L2 cache and the L1 Instruction cache or directly from DRAM to the L1 Instruction cache), and the detailed workflow of CPU loading data (from DRAM to the L3->L2->L1D?).

Comment: Thanks for reminding, but I do think this question is answerable and practical. Because right now we are facing a system optimization problem that requires a clear workflow of the execution of a CPU.

Comment: Realistically the workflow you describe is the same between an original 8086 and a Xeon released in 2019.  Silicon might be faster, there might be additional instructions, but the architecture really hasn’t changed.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound, really appreciate it. Do you have some detailed documentation describing it?